# Can PostgreSQL materialized view refresh run concurrently with pg_dump?

Tags: postgresql, materialized-views, pg-dump

I think there is a problem between `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW` and `pg_dump`.

The first has to wait for the second (or it's the opposite?).

Why please?

Comment: Did you use refresh concurrent?

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-refreshmaterializedview.html) describes the `CONCURRENTLY` option of `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW`:

> Without this option a refresh which affects a lot of rows will tend to use fewer resources and complete more quickly, but could block other connections which are trying to read from the materialized view.

So the materialized view is blocked for all concurrent access while it is being refreshed. `pg_dump`, on the other hand, needs to access the materialized view. So whoever comes first will block the other.

There are two options:

- if you can define a unique index on the materialized view, and you don't mind if the refresh takes longer, you can use `REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY`
- use `pg_basebackup` rather than `pg_dump` to backup your database